# Selecting and using values from API populated dropdown in a React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a reusable dropdown for using in a React edit form.  Currently you select a record from the table to edit, which opens a modal with the edit form.  The current values in the edit form are populated from the current values pulled together in an API, not the full item record.
I am doing the Axios call and setting the options all within the dropdown component, so all I have to do is pass the URL of the API via props for each dropdown.  Eventually I will have forms with multiple dropdowns, so I figured this was the easiest way to accomplish this.

Here is my situation, with examples of the data:

- The API used for the dropdown supplies the values 'id' and 'name' for each record (in this case Departments).

```
    "name": "Tools",
    "id": "1",
```

- The record I select to edit has a value of 'departmentName' but does not include a department Id as a value.

```
    "name": "23456",
    "description": "New Location",
    "departmentName": "Tools"
```

- The post API is using this JSON format for updating the record, requiring and ID for the department:

```
     "name": "23456",
     "description": "New Location",
     "departmentOther": {
         "id": 1
     }
```

Currently, I can populate the dropdown with a list of departments, display the current value of departmentName, and select a new value. As long as I use *value={option.name}* as the value of my menu items. If I use *value={option.value}* the dropdown displays an empty string as the current value.
How can I take the values provided from the selected record and the dropdown list and supply the JSON needed for the PUT request?

I am also receiving this warning, since it doesn't seem to be comparing the current value to the options and seeing a matching value despite there being one:

*You have provided an out-of-range value `Tools` for the select (name="departmentName") component.'*

Here is my code:

**Component as used in form**

```
    <Controls.Dropdown
        // onChange={handleInputChange}
        label='Department'
        name='departmentName'
        prompt='Select A Department...'
        url='/api/maintain/departments/'
        value={values.departmentName}
     />
```

**OnChange Function**

```
        const [values, setValues] = React.useState({} as any);

    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({
            ...values,
             [name]: ( typeof value === 'string' ? (value).replace(/ +(?= )/g, '').trimStart() : value ) // removes leading space & multiple spaces if value is a string
        });
        if (validateOnChange)
          { validate({ [name]: value }); }
    };
```

**Dropdown**

```
        export default function Dropdown(props) {
      const { error = null, label, onChange, prompt, value, url, ...other } = props;
      const [departmentId, setDepartmentId] = React.useState(null);
      const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
      const dropdownUrl = environment.originURL + environment.apiUrl + url; 

    // Fetch Data for Dropdown list
      React.useEffect(() => {
           const fetchData = async () => {
             const res = await axios.get(dropdownUrl);
             setOptions( res.data );
           };
           fetchData();
       }, [setOptions]); 

    // Dropdown List
      return(
        <>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl} variant='outlined' >
            <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
            <Select
                defaultValue=''
                // onChange={onChange}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  const { value } = e.target;
                  value={value === undefined || null ? '' : value}
                  // value={departmentId}
                  onChange(value);
                }}
                value={value}
                {...other}
                {...(error && {error: true, helperText: error})}
            >
                <MenuItem>{prompt}</MenuItem>
                {options.map((option, id) => (
                    <MenuItem
                        key={option.id}
                        value={option.value}
                        // value={option.value}
                    >
                        {option.name}
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
        </>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the department Id as well. First you have to make a state for it and then whenever a new item is clicked/changed, you need to update the state as well. Here is the updated code for Dropdown.

```
// Dropdown

export default function Dropdown(props) {
  const { error = null, label, onChange, prompt, value, url, ...other } = props;
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
  const [departmentId, setDepartmentId] = React.useState(null);
  const dropdownUrl = environment.originURL + environment.apiUrl + url; 

// Fetch Data for Dropdown list
  React.useEffect(() => {
       const fetchData = async () => {
         const res = await axios.get(dropdownUrl);
         setOptions( res.data );
       };
       fetchData();
   }, [setOptions]); 

// Dropdown List
  return(
    <>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl} variant='outlined' >
            <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
            <Select
                defaultValue=''
                onChange={(e) => {
                    const { value } = e.target;
                    setDepartmentId(value);
                    onChange(value);
                }}
                value={departmentId}
                {...other}
                {...(error && {error: true, helperText: error})}
            >
                <MenuItem>{prompt}</MenuItem>
                {options.map((option, id) => (
                    <MenuItem
                        key={option.id}
                        value={option.value}
                    >
                        {option.name}
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>

    </>
    );
}
```

And i think it should work now.

Comment: Your solutions seem to make a lot of sense, but I am still unable to make this work.  I have updated my code to my current state. Getting a console error of "onChange is not a function", "component is changing from an uncontrolled input to controlled".  Additionally, I am still getting the warning stated above, but instead of the current name it is 'null', and my current name is not displaying in the dropdown until i select a new value.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your check on value in onChange function seems incorrect. It seems to me that you want to check for undefined or null values. Following check might be correct one.

`value == null ? '' : value`

or

`(value === null || value === undefined) ? '' : value`